# How to hide values from client in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router

Hi I'm very beginner on Angularjs and I'm trying to build basic login application. I want to hide some values from client like api url, api keys but i couldn't find a way to do it.

I also want to modify my directive via controller to change view if user is logged in or not. I may use scope for it but i dont know if it is safe and I also don't know how to change view in controller for this purpose.

How can I do these things? Any help will be appreciate. Thanks.

Comment: If it's accessible in JavaScript, it's accessible by the user.

Comment: so isn't there anyway to hide api keys. I think there should be. Otherwise app will be weak.

Comment: @ErdiKöse Surprise! All "secure" apps are a little weak. Hence, each Call of Duty is available on Russian websites a week after release. JavaScript is simply more obviously "readable" than most clientside programs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular JS is client side rendering framework which leaves data security issues, you can cure it up to some extent by minifying and concatenating you final production code using grunt or gulp but this is not a permanent solution.

I stumbled upon this github project https://github.com/saymedia/angularjs-server
it claims to do server side rendering of AngularJS with node.js, but for this you need to know basic node.js

you can try Ember.JS. It gives you both options of server side and client side rendering and its faster than angularJS when data set is realistically large because it does not render the whole DOM when model changes rather it patches the existing DOM to reflect the changes

Comment: checkout this article [link](http://www.code-sample.com/2015/03/top-10-security-risks-in-angularjs.html)